# Windows 10, Taskbar Multiple Icon Windows, Can't Tell The Difference Between

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

Not sure that I am using the proper terminology, but my problem is this and described in the photo.

Say I have 4 Windows Explorer instances open and am constantly going between them. When I hover over the Windows Explorer icon on the taskbar, or use  alt-tab or windows-tab function, if the file path is long, I can't see what the actual folder is that I am clicking on. Because all 4 windows may have the same beginning file paths (ex: c:/windows/users/default/etc. etc.), they all look the same.

Is there a way to fix this? Thanks!!

Screen shot showing how all windows appear to be the same even if they go to different locations:

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: Could you simply explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: All i want to do is know which icon to click in the above screenshot. Because the file path appears identical for each window (it is only the first 50% of the file path that is actually identical but it is all that is displayed) I dont know which icon leads to what folder. I then have to click between all windows using luck to hope I find the one I want the first try.

Comment: I don't understand why you opened three (or four) identical paths. What file are you looking for?

Comment: If you move your cursor over the thumbnails, a tooltip should appear that shows the full window title.

Comment: Spike_66- Thanks for your response, but they are not identical paths, they just appear to be identical because Windows truncates the full length. This is exactly my issue- I cant tell which window I am clicking on.

Comment: Sonickyle27- Thanks for your response, but windows doesnt show the full path when you cursor over the thumbnail. Most of my files have a long path length due to my organizational structure.